# Maximum number of columns that can be acquired by "Scan()" of "go-sql-driver/mysql"

Tags: mysql, go

I'm using `github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql` to retrieve data from MySQL.
The number of record is only one, but the number of columns is about 30.

I tried to get the value of each column using `Scan()` as follows.
But I was only able to get the values ​​of the first 4 columns.
The value of other columns were `nil` or `0`.

Is there a maximum number of columns in this package or the `Scan()` function?
I looked at the package source code but could not find such a constraint.

```golang
var db *sql.DB
query := "select * from tbl where id = ?"

row := db.QueryRowContext(ctx, query, args)
err = row.Scan(
    &val1,
    &val2,
    ...
    &val30,
)
```

Comment: `Is there a maximum number of columns in this package or the Scan() function?` -- No. But MySQL itself has a limit of 4096 columns: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/column-count-limit.html

Comment: Thank you so much :) Maybe, my code has some bug... I'll try investigate